# how to slide between images in the same viewcintroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I want to have group of images as a thumbnail in my app, and I want to slide between them at the same view controller.

same as this App "How to Tie a Scarf HD"

http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/65/59/b0/6559b0bc-0187-17fd-3172-c5f7d55a0b68/screen480x480.jpeg

What do I need and how can I apply it ?

can anyone help please ?

Comment: Don't really know how do you want it to look , but I think you should start from `UIGestureRecognizer` then when you recognize the swipe and its direction you can add animation of moving images 
Still I don't know how you want it to be like , and I have no idea what you have already done , I just think you should start from here.

Comment: please review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: what I want is an image gallery that all the images is shown in one horizontal row. at the meddle of the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the scrollview in your viewcontroller, set the content size of scroll view enough to fit all of your images and set the content offset to load the image whichever you are clicking in the thumbnail. For code and more information , look in the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675312/load-images-on-a-image-view-using-horizontal-scrolling)

Look to the accepted answer.

Comment: thank you for you help,
I tried to apply what is in the link you provided but the problem the images is not scrolling, and is it possible to use UIpageControl object to indicate the image location ?